# Jquery drag + drop issue

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, droppable

I have the following JSfiddle code (link below)
. I am having problems fixing it so the the items can be dragged within the white box area.

Scenario: The User 1 box is the base and all the other User boxes should be within the User 1 white content DIV. Then if for instance you drag user 4 into user 2 the user 4 should be within the white content box of user 2 and so on. At the moment it will just drag into the grey part of the user 2 box.

Any ideas on how to setup the DIVs?

I know its to do with the HTML setup just can't think of how to fix it

https://jsfiddle.net/euf1s9gc/3/

```
'use strict'

 $(document).ready(function(){

var resp =[{"id":"1","name":"User","title":"1","parentID":"9","base":"1"},  
{"id":"2","name":"User","title":"2","parentID":"1","base":"0"},
{"id":"3","name":" User","title":"3","parentID":"1","base":"0"},
{"id":"4","name":"User","title":"4","parentID":"1","base":"0"}];

createList(resp);
setDragDrop();


function createList(data){

jQuery.each(data, function() {

    var baseUsed =false;
    if(this.base == 1 && baseUsed ==false){

        //Problem in the setup  of the HTML
        $('.containers').append("<div class='popup' id='parentID_"+this.id+"'><div class='header'>"+this.name+" ("+this.title+")</div><div class='content'></div></div>");

        baseUsed = true;//to stop replication

    }else{

        $('#parentID_'+this.parentID).append("<div id='parentID_"+this.id+"' class='popup'><div class='header'>"+this.name+" ("+this.title+")</div><div class='content'></div></div>");
    }

});

}

function setDragDrop(){


    $('.containers .popup').droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      //  accept: '.object',
        out: function() {
            $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
         },
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            var targetId = this.id;
            var userId = (ui.draggable).get(0).id;

            $(ui.draggable).addClass("insidePopup");
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });


    $('.popup').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        containment:"parent"
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to actually fix the droppable part, so it drops within the .content I just need to figure out the setup part.

code modified
    $('.containers .popup .content').droppable({